# extjs 4.1.0 how to get textfield values without using their id

Tags: extjs4.1

I have one Textfield, Combo and a Radio. I want to get values of these 3 fields on clicking one button. How I can get the values of above 3 without using `Ext.getCmp('id').getValue();`

Is there any other method is their to get the values,
please let me know.

Comment: Are these controls within a from? If yes you can get do some thing along the lines of someFormPanel.getForm().getValues().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you have contained your fields and the button you want to click to get their values.

You can navigate up and down your containers

```
var TheComponent = this.up('form').down('#MyTextField')
```

This climbs up your container hierarchy until it finds a 'form' container (doesn't matter what its Id or name is) and them climbs down until it finds a component with the id: 'MyTextField'

If your radio button is in a radio button group container you can retrieve an object that has all your 'on' key/values.

If your container is a form you can use the method proposed by lzhaki and retrieve an object that contains all the values on your form. Just remember that combo boxes behave differently to text boxes.

Each of these methods will return either a single value or an object containing a group of values.

Answer (score 0):

In ExtJS 4.1, I found the prior example was close, but incorrect:

```
var TheComponent = this.up('form').down('#MyTextField')
```

There is no "down" method in the form object (apparently form fields aren't included in the down method's navigation logic).

Here's what worked for me to set initial focus on an edit field within a form.

```
var theForm = this.down('form').getForm();
var theField = theForm.findField('idEditVolname');
theField.focus();
```

You still must use `getForm()` to get the embedded form object, followed by `findField()` to locate the specific field - at least that's what works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still relevant, but here goes.
First of all, in Extjs4 and up, you use `Ext.ComponentQuery.query()` instead of `Ext.getCmp()`.
What this allows you to do is access any xtype you have directly, just like the `up`, and `down` methods mentioned in other answers, but this method doesn't need any anchors as it searches the entire component hierarchy. Since you have only one of each element on the page that would be very easy to achieve without using id's.
I would name the main panel that contains the fields, but that's just for convenience.
Look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bldoron/cdVn9/)

The code is really simple:

```
var panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    name: 'myForm',
    title: 'Sample Test',
    layout: 'anchor',
    height: 200,
    items: [{
        xtype:'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'text',
        value: 'Oh yeah!'
    }]    
});

var myVal = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('panel[name=myForm] textfield')[0];
alert (myVal.getValue());
```

The same can be done with the `radio` and `combo` fields, and you don't need a form for that, though it is more logical that way.